# Updating Axis In Matplotlib Based on Dynamic Values

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, plot, graph

I am working on a project in which I read in values from a text file that dynamically updates with two values separated by a space. These values are taken put into a list and then both plotted with each being a point on the y-axis and time being on the x-axis. In the first set of code provided below I am able to take in the values and plot them, then save that plot as a png. However, the plot does not seem to update the time values as more data comes in. But the graph does reflect the changes in the values.

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Jul 25 11:23:14 2016

@author: aruth3
"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import time
import datetime

class reader():
    """Reads in a comma seperated txt file and stores the two strings in two variables"""

    def __init__(self, file_path):
        """Initialize Reader Class"""
        self.file_path = file_path

    # Read File store in f -- Change the file to your file path
    def read_file(self):
        """Reads in opens file, then stores it into file_string as a string"""
        f = open(self.file_path)
        # Read f, stores string in x
        self.file_string = f.read()

    def split_string(self):
        """Splits file_string into two variables and then prints them"""
        # Splits string into two variables
        try:
            self.val1, self.val2 = self.file_string.split(' ', 1)
        except ValueError:
            print('Must Have Two Values Seperated By a Space in the .txt!!')
            sys.exit('Terminating Program -- Contact Austin')
        #print(val1)  # This is where you could store each into a column on the mysql server
        #print(val2)

    def getVal1(self):
            return self.val1

    def getVal2(self):
            return self.val2

read = reader('testFile.txt')
run = True
tempList = []
humList = []
numList = [] # Represents 2 Secs
my_xticks = []
i = 0

while(run):
    plt.ion()
    read.read_file()
    read.split_string()
    tempList.append(read.getVal1())
    humList.append(read.getVal2())
    numList.append(i)
    i = i + 1
    my_xticks.append(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M'))
    plt.ylim(0,125)
    plt.xticks(numList,my_xticks)
    plt.locator_params(axis='x',nbins=4)
    plt.plot(numList,tempList, 'r', numList, humList, 'k')
    plt.savefig('plot.png')
    time.sleep(10) # Runs every 2 seconds
```

The testFile.txt has two values `100 90` and can be updated on the fly and change in the graph. But as time goes on you will notice (if you run the code) that the times are not updating.

To remedy the *time not updating* issue I figure that modifying the lists using pop would allow the first value to leave and then another value when it loops back around. This worked as far as the time updating was concerned, however this ended up messing up the graph:
[Link To Bad Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u6h0.png)

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Aug  2 09:42:16 2016

@author: aruth3
"""

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Jul 25 11:23:14 2016

@author:
"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import time
import datetime

class reader():
    """Reads in a comma seperated txt file and stores the two strings in two variables"""

    def __init__(self, file_path):
        """Initialize Reader Class"""
        self.file_path = file_path

    # Read File store in f -- Change the file to your file path
    def read_file(self):
        """Reads in opens file, then stores it into file_string as a string"""
        f = open(self.file_path)
        # Read f, stores string in x
        self.file_string = f.read()

    def split_string(self):
        """Splits file_string into two variables and then prints them"""
        # Splits string into two variables
        try:
            self.val1, self.val2 = self.file_string.split(' ', 1)
        except ValueError:
            print('Must Have Two Values Seperated By a Space in the .txt!!')
            sys.exit('Terminating Program -- Contact')
        #print(val1)  # This is where you could store each into a column on the mysql server
        #print(val2)

    def getVal1(self):
            return self.val1

    def getVal2(self):
            return self.val2

read = reader('testFile.txt')
run = True
tempList = []
humList = []
numList = [] # Represents 2 Secs
my_xticks = []
i = 0
n = 0 # DEBUG

while(run):
    plt.ion()
    read.read_file()
    read.split_string()
    if n == 4:
        my_xticks.pop(0)
        tempList.pop(0)
        humList.pop(0)
        numList = [0,1,2]
        i = 3
        n = 3
    tempList.append(read.getVal1())
    humList.append(read.getVal2())
    numList.append(i)
    i = i + 1
    my_xticks.append(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M:%S')) # Added seconds for debug
    plt.ylim(0,125)
    plt.xticks(numList,my_xticks)
    plt.locator_params(axis='x',nbins=4)
    plt.plot(numList,tempList, 'r', numList, humList, 'k')
    plt.savefig('plot.png')
    time.sleep(10) # Runs every 2 seconds
    n = n + 1
    print(n) # DEBUG
    print(numList)# DEBUG
    print('-------')# DEBUG
    print(my_xticks)# DEBUG
    print('-------')# DEBUG
    print(tempList)# DEBUG
    print('-------')# DEBUG
    print(humList)# DEBUG
```

So my question is how can I create a graph that when new values come in it kicks out the first value in the list, thus updating the time, but also provides an accurate graph of the data without the glitching?

The pop off the list seems like a good idea but I am not sure why it is messing up the graph?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question may be more appropriate at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Pseudo Code

```
plotData = []
for (1 to desired size)
  plotData[i] = 0

 while data
   update time
   plotData.push(data with time)
   plotData.popTop(oldest data)
   Draw plotData
 end while
```